# How to fix locale issue on Google Maps Android v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I am using Google Maps v2 Android sdk and when changing locale of the app to Armenian, Maps doesn't show street names (only shows some of them in English).

Code used for changing locale:

```
    private static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    Configuration config = new Configuration(resources.getConfiguration());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
        context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
    } else {
        config.locale = locale;
        resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    return context;
}
```

I know that there is some issue related to another language:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36823099

[image: English locale]
[image: Armenian locale]

Comment: Just a speculation, but is it possible that Maps hasn't gotten around to completely handling all the maps for Armenia in Armenian?

Comment: Even if the maps in Armenian aren't available (but i can see armenian names on the web part and Maps application), why doesn't it show names in English? How to change Maps locale?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, some languages can only be served using the v3.1.0 Beta Maps SDK for Android client library. I would give this a try.

Follow the migration guide https://goo.gle/v3-migration-guide

This is a beta release, give your feedback in the new component of the Issue Tracker [https://goo.gle/gmp-android-sdk-beta-issues] to help exit beta as quickly as possible.